# add a property to a Json array with Gson

Tags: javascript, json, gson

I am serializing a list of objects with Gson like this:

```
String responseMessage = new Gson().toJson(pages.get(pagenumber));
```

I want to add another property to be read in javascript but that is unrelated to the list:

```
{"numberofpages":x}
```

I tried this:

```
    JsonElement responsemessage = new Gson().toJsonTree(pages.get(pagenumber));
   JsonObject message = (JsonObject) responsemessage;
   message.addProperty("numberofpages",numberofpages);
```

... but I couldn't because `responsemessage` was a JSONArray. How can I encode more information in this String version of `responseMessage` to be read in javascript:

```
$.get("/lod1/Data",{pagenumber: page},function(list){
      console.log(list);
      //???
      //if(list.numberofpages == 5){

       // }

        $.each(list,function(index,card){
           $("#questionsforsets").append('<tr><td class="questioncell"><div class="longtexttd">'+card.card+'</div></td><td>'+card.category+'</td><td>'+card.made+'</td><td>'+card.missed+'</td></tr>'); 
        });
  },"json");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you found out, you cant add a property to a JSON Array.

If your `responsemessage` is an array, and you need to pass another value along with it, you should put this array and that value into a new object. Something like this should work:

```
JsonObject responseObject = new JsonObject();
responseObject.addProperty("pages", responsemessage);
responseObject.addProperty("numOfPages", numberOfPages);
```

(of course your JS code handling this response will need to be adjusted accordingly)

Comment: Cool, so to access the list it would be: $.each(list.pages,...  correct ?

Comment: well, yeah (and I would rename `list` into `response`, since it isnt a list anymore)